# What values do the <empty> elements created by new Array() have?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm quite confused by these little guys. After I encountered some funny behavior between them and Array.prototype.filter I fooled around in re.pl trying to understand their true value. But it seems like they switch from `<empty>` to `undefined` depending on who's looking (at least in re.pl and node, they're logged as `undefined` in this environment).

```js
 
    let emptyArr = new Array(5);
    //set up two control elements
    emptyArr[0] = 0;
    emptyArr[4] = undefined;
    
    
    console.log('\nemptyArr:', emptyArr)
    console.log('\npeeking at an empty element:', emptyArr[1])
    console.log('\nfilter for undefined elements:', emptyArr.filter(e => e === undefined))
    console.log('\nfilter for any element:', 
       emptyArr.filter(e => {
          console.log("ele:", e)
          return true
       })
    ) // only two elements are registered here

    console.log('\nmappedEmpty:', emptyArr.map(e => e)) //everything is preserved

    console.log('\ngenerated array', Array.from(emptyArr)) 
    console.log('\nalways true filter on generated array:', Array.from(emptyArr).filter(e => true)) // empties are now 'true' undefined
```

What's the story here? Quirky array prototype methods or a secret ultra-false-y value?

Comment: `<empty>` entries are missing key–value entries in an array. An `undefined` entry is just a key with the value `undefined`, but `<empty>` does not even have a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the story here? Quirky array prototype methods or a secret ultra-false-y value?

**Arrays are objects.** Elements of the array are simply properties of the underlying object. Accessing a property that doesn't exist returns `undefined`. Therefore when you access `emptyArr[1]` you get `undefined`. Looking at the console of Chrome might help:

[image]

As you can see, `0` and `4` exist because you created those entries by assigning to them. `1`, `2` and `3` don't exist.

These positions with no value are often referred to as "holes". Your array has holes at positions `1`, `2` and `3`. An array with holes is also called "sparse array".

Most array methods (`.filter`, `.map`, etc) *skip over holes*. We can easily prove this for some methods:

```js
// Array#map
console.log([,,,42].map(() => 21)); // [,,,21], not [21,21,21,21]
// Array#every
console.log([,,,42].every(x => x === 42)); // true, not false
```

Of course we could also just look at the [language specification](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/), where it says for [`Array#every`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-array.prototype.every) for example:

> *callbackfn* is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

`Array.from` on the other hand explicitly looks at the `.length` property of the value passed to it and it will copy any property/element between `0` and `.length`. In other words, it does *not* skip holes.

Look at the difference between the arrays in the Chrome console:

[image]

Worth noting maybe that `arr.length` doesn't care about holes. It will always be the highest *set* index in the array + 1.

Answer (score 0):

They are `undefined`. It just depends on the engine how it displays them, but trying to access them returns `undefined`, because that's what they are - elements that have not been defined.

For example the Chrome console will print `> (5) [empty × 5]` while node prints `[ , , , ,  ]` for the same `new Array(5)`. It's just a more visual representation than, say, showing `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually they do not exist. Imagine arrays being objects, using `new Array(5)` you will get:

```
{
 length:5
}
```

So like objects they return undefined for nonset values:

```
array[3] // undefined
```

But that doesnt mean theres a property set to undefined. That changes when you use `Array.from` . You can imagine it doing sth like

```
for(var i = 0; i < oldarray.lemgth; i++){
 newarray[i] = oldarray[i];
}
```

So after the `Array.from` call itll look like this:

```
{
length:5,
0:undefined,
1:undefined,
2:undefined,
3:undefined,
4:undefined
}
```